# Connect webhost database to android database

Tags: php, android, sql

I developed a web application based on PHP, now I built an android application too.

I know I can use SQLite for storing information, but I want to connect android database to my webhost database so that the information can be accessible by two applications.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: that's not how you do cloud apps, you maintain a local sqlite version of the relevant data and sync using json or xml.

Comment: as I am new to android could you tell my how to do that?

Comment: that's a very broad topic. but plenty of examples out there.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way to access database outside device, you need to write some web services which will return data in json (better option) or xml format and then you can parse it and use information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP script in order to accomplish that.

http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/connect-android-to-mysql-database-tutorial.8339/

Answer (score 0):

Although Full implementation requires lot of code and instead of reinventing the wheel its better u checkout  smart implementation given in the links below which will help u out.

The following [Tutorial #01](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) and [Tutorial #02](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)  might help you out.

1- Connect Android to Remote Database

2- Using Json (API) to parse data from and into android to server

3- Parse Request and Process

4- Save Information in Local Android Sqllite database.